# Mockito: Always returns zero resultant from SQLQuery using Mockito

Tags: mockito, junit4

I have created a mockito test for a method, but it always returns empty. I checked there is a data for given condition(email and batchId) in DB. Where i am going wrong?

```
@Test
public void  testGetStudentResultByNameAndId() {
    String name = "fgafsg@gmail.com";
    Number batchId = 23;

    Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = Mockito.mock(SQLQuery.class);
    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(session.createQuery(" select id , tracking_type_id , date_created from STUDENT_RESULT_INFO "+
             " where name = '" + name + "' and  batch_id = "+batchId  +  " and tracking_type_id in (1,2) ")).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Mockito.when(sqlQuery.addScalar("id", StringType.INSTANCE)).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Mockito.when(sqlQuery.addScalar("tracking_type_id", StringType.INSTANCE)).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Mockito.when(sqlQuery.addScalar("date_created", TimestampType.INSTANCE)).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Mockito.when(sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
    Mockito.when(sqlQuery.list()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());
    System.out.println("sqlQuery.list() :"+sqlQuery.list());
}
```

My output:

```
query.list() :[]
```

Comment: you setup mock to return empty array `Mockito.when(sqlQuery.list()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());`  The mock is doing exactly what it was told to do.

Comment: @Nkosi Ok, then what should i return?. Because i am not returning any domain here, this will rule out returning domain. i understand that i need to return list and want to just return 3 fields as in query. how to get that resulttant?.

Comment: I assume that your goal is to test the class `SQLQuerry`, you should rather **instantiate** it rather than **mock** it:
`SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuerry();`

Comment: @Benoit  no i want to do mock testing.

Comment: @daisy But what is "mock testing" ? What is the goal of your test class ? What class/method/feature are you trying to test ?

Comment: you are getting exactly what you have told your test to return.